# Best practice : launching activity from navigation?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, navigation-drawer

I have navigation drawer which using mostly `fragments` for loading views but one `activity` which confuse me.you can see my drawer below and assume that i have to start activity when clicking the option `Profile`.if i starting the activity do i need to return to home screen or i need to return to the fragment from where the activity launched ?

***Problem 2 :*** Am replacing the selected drawer icon as you can see in the attachment below.when clicking the `Profile` option do i need to replace the `Profile` option icon as selected which is not feeling comfortable for me.?

***And the genuine Problem :*** Drawer look like stucked or not properly ie , not smoothly closing when calling `startActivity`.

***And one more :*** What about finishing navigation `activity` when launching new `activity` and starting freshly after `finish` the new one ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answer for problem 1: It is depend on you where you are writing a code i. e. click event for drawer layout. if you are using fragment then write a code in fragment and fragment is a part of activity so obviously you will going to use getActivity().startActivity(intent);

Answer for problem 2: This is not mandatory that use have to replace a icon. you can use tint functionality to change the icon color or you can use selector or use can use ripple which is default in android 5.0 and above.

Answer for problem 3: Sorry i am facing also some problem so will update on this soon.

Answer for problem 4: Why you are finishing navigation activity. Ultimately you will come back to navigation activity so don't finish navigation activity. Just start new activity. once new activity finish it will come back to navigation activity.

Hope this will help for you.